# Ethereum Solidity Division

Tags: solidity

```
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }
```

When I call the function above as library in my solidity code `107752139522000.div(1099511627776)` I receive `97`, when the actual result is `98`

Here is an example of the same problem in eth fiddle (deploy and call the function div): https://ethfiddle.com/EL2MbHI8h_

Comment: The actual result is 97.99999999995634...

Comment: how did you determine that is the actual result ?

Comment: I used python, but any calculator that support large integers should do fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. Solidity does integer math. This means results are truncated (not rounded). 107752139522000/1099511627776 is a little less than 98, so the result is 97.

Comment: so would simply adding +1 compensate for this, what are the limitations of this approach ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? It's hard to make suggestions if we don't know what you're trying to do.